# Should it be "it is threatened" or "these are threatened" in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> India has always professed its desire to have friendly relations with all countries but has been equally firm in safeguarding its interests when **it** is threatened.

I think the above sentence is correct with **it** being used for India.

But in my book it is written that instead of **"it is threatened"** **"these are threatened"** should be used.

Comment: So, what is your question? If it's only to ask if it's correct, that's proofreading. Is there a reason why you think it might not be correct?

Comment: //India has always professed its desire to have friendly relations with all countries but has been equally firm in safeguarding its interests when (it is) threatened.// Just try reading without 'it is' used towards the end; doesn't it still make sense?

Comment: @RamPillai It makes sense

Comment: @KshitijSingh, my question was, "doesn't it still make sense?" Perhaps you skipped reading the word 'still' where I intended that it made sense in both ways. :)